# Distance = rate * time calculation

Tags: javascript, return

I am trying to write  an **anonymous function in JavaScript**  that will calculate and return the distance travelled using the formula rate * time. The function definition needs to be assigned to a variable. then the function needs to be called using that variable.

But I am having trouble with the code, any pointed on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head><title>Anonymous Function</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var d = function(){
    }

   return d;
 }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var rate = prompt('how fast plan to drive (in mph)');
         rate = parseInt(rate);
      var time = prompt('how much time do you plan to drive? (in minutes)');
          time = parseInt(time);
      distance = rate * time;
      d = distance;
</script>
</big>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to write a function to do the calculation, why do you have the calculations outside the function?

Comment: Note that your `distance = rate * time` formula is incorrect if you're asking the user to enter speed in mph and time in minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var distance = function(rate, time) {
    return rate * time;
}

var rate = prompt('how fast plan to drive (in mph)');
rate = parseInt(rate);
var time = prompt('how much time do you plan to drive? (in minutes)');
time = parseInt(time);
d = distance(rate, time);
alert("You traveled "+d+" miles");
```